# what is the difference between hash map, hash set, hash dictionary?

Tags: terminology, hash

Can somebody explain me the difference between the following structures:

1. Hash Map
2. Hash Table,
3. Hash Set, and
4. Hash Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

HashMap, HashTable, and HashDictionary all mean a dictionary, mapping unique unordered keys to corresponding values, implemented using hashcodes.

HashSet means a unique, unordered set, implemented using hashcodes.