# Hash-sets, Hash-maps and Hash-tables?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, set, terminology

Is Hash-map exactly the same with a Hash-table? Based on this [what is the difference between hash map, hash set, hash dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851811/what-is-the-difference-between-hash-map-hash-set-hash-dictionary), it is.

Also, a Hash-set implies unique elements, but in which side, the keys?

---

<sub>If it makes the answer easier, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) could come into play...</sub>

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a question link to its duplicate. The linked question already provides a suitable answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, **no**. I can't understand the uniqueness that comes with the Hash-set from the other answer. :/

Comment: @gsamaras A hashset is just a set - think of it like a map/table/dictionary, but with just keys, no values.

Comment: The table is the underlying data structure; sets and maps are *applications* of that data structure.

Comment: @gsamaras: Then put a bounty on it. Don't just repost the same question.

Comment: But it's not my question LightnessRacesinOrbit. @J... you mean it has no buckets?

Comment: @gsamaras "But it's not my question" you can still do it, and [get an additional badge out of it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hmm useful information! I will keep that in mind for the next time, since I *believe* that your answer is far better than the other one.

Comment: @gsamaras To be fair, it's because you allowed to make comparisons to C++: comparing to something you already know makes the job of explaining a lot easier.

Comment: I know @dasblinkenlight, that's why I said *I believe*, thank you again, everything looks crystal clear now! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashMap` has roughly the same functionality as `HashTable`, in the sense that it is an associative storage of keys to values. The main difference is that `HashTable` is synchronized and does not allow `null`s on either side, while `HashMap` is not synchronized and allows `null`s on both sides.

> Hash-set implies unique elements, but in which side, the keys?

`HashSet`, however, is an entirely different collection - it has only one side, the keys. You can think of it as a `HashMap` with no associated values, or with all associated values being the same. It is similar to [`std::unordered_set<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) of C++, except for the way the generic behavior is implemented. `HashMap`, on the other hand, is similar to [`std::unordered_map<K,V>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) of C++.

Comment: Are you talking about Java classes `HashMap` and `HashTable`?  Java's `HashTable` is synchronized, but I don't think this is generally true of all hash table implementations, and not of anything standard in C++ (that I'm aware of).

Comment: @J... I did talk specifically about Java `HashTable` and Java `HashMap`, not realizing that the question hasn't been tagged for Java. You are absolutely right, generally, hash table and hash map containers do not talk about synchronization.